# Why can't the wildcard expression be used as a non-root user?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

I am using a wildcard expression to match a filename.

This is what happens with a normal, non-root user:

```
debian@MiWiFi-R3-srv:~$ sudo ls  /var/log/apache2/*[0-9].gz
ls: cannot access '/var/log/apache2/*[0-9].gz': No such file or directory
```

And this is what happens after I switch to the root user with `sudo su` and try the same command:

```
root@MiWiFi-R3-srv:/home/debian# ls  /var/log/apache2/*[0-9].gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.10.gz  /var/log/apache2/error.log.10.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.11.gz  /var/log/apache2/error.log.11.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.12.gz  /var/log/apache2/error.log.12.gz
```

Why can this wildcard expression be used as `root`, but not as a normal, non-root user?

Comment: The expression you are using is wildcard, since `ls` doesn't support Regular expressions.

Comment: `sudo ls` does not support ,`ls` support?

Comment: No `sudo` does nothing but just elevates an executable or command / shell function. Here actually the executable used is `ls` and since `ls` does not use regex then °sudo ls` will not also. Both use wildcards. And you don't need to bother about this, as the expression you are even using is wildcard. Here `*` means any character (in regex it meant 0 or more instances of previous character), `[0-9]` means any character in range of 0 to 9 (which is same as regex). And if you used regex you would need to escape `.` using backslash because it means any character in regex.

Comment: If it works as you say, `sudo su && ls /var/log/apache2/*[0-9].gz` should show nothing.

Comment: Maybe the Apache log files are being created after you have executed the first command with `sudo`? Execute `ls -la` in `su` shell and get the creation time??

Comment: Does `ls /var/log/apache2/` (without the globbing) work from your regular user account?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove files from a root-owned directory using sudo with wildcards](https://superuser.com/questions/980472/remove-files-from-a-root-owned-directory-using-sudo-with-wildcards)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In `/var/log/apache2/*[0-9].gz` the substring `*[0-9]` is handled by the [pathname expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06) mechanism of the shell. Not of `sudo` nor `ls`. Of the *shell*. This happens before `sudo` or `ls` even starts.

To expand `/var/log/apache2/*[0-9].gz` the shell needs to examine the content of `/var/log/apache2/`. In my Debian 10 the permissions are `rwxr-x---`, the ownership is `root:adm`. In effect the root's shell can examine the content but a regular user's shell cannot.

Therefore the pattern gets expanded for root, but it stays verbatim for a regular user. Neither `sudo` nor `ls` expand the pattern and eventually the regular user's (elevated) `ls` tries to list information about `/var/log/apache2/*[0-9].gz` exactly; there is no such file or directory.

This should work for a regular user:

```
sudo sh -c 'ls /var/log/apache2/*[0-9].gz'
```

In this case `sudo` will run *elevated* `sh` and this shell will successfully expand the pattern.

(At first I thought `sudo -s …` would do it, but [no](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484362/108618).)

Comment: It helps to understand that `*[0-9].gz`, even though unusual, is a perfectly legitimate filename on Unix/Linux. It _could_ exist. So when `ls` is asked if that file exists, it must check that exact name.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Windows/DOS, globs are expanded by the shell before running the command in Unix systems.  The shell in this case is running with your UID, not root, so it can't read that directory.

**The default behaviour in the no-match case is to pass on the glob expression literally.**  e.g. if you run `ls xyz*xyz` in your normal shell, you'll see `ls: cannot access 'xyz*xyz': No such file or directory` from `ls`, because it got that string as an argument.

Just like if you'd run `ls '*'` to pass `*` as a literal string to `ls`.  (Quote-removal is also the shell's job, so a command can't tell whether its arg was quoted or not.)

You can change this behaviour in bash, e.g. `shopt -s failglob` means the same `ls xyz*xyz` command will give  `bash: no match: xyz*xyz` *without* invoking `ls` at all.  (If you'd used `sudo`, you would have noticed that it didn't prompt you for a password before getting this error message.)

`failglob` produces the same "no match" error when trying to read a directory that you don't have read permission on, unfortunately not warning you about the EPERM error that bash go when it made an `open` system-call on the directory. `bash: no match: /var/log/private/*`

(There's also `shopt -s nullglob`, where a non-matching glob expression is removed instead of passed on literally.  Then your `sudo ls /...*` command would have confusingly just run as `sudo ls`.  This is perhaps useful for scripting where you might want to do `*.gz *.tgz *.tar` or something, and not get errors from the failed expansion.  Probably not something you'd usually want for interactive use.)

---

You can use `shopt -u failglob` or whatever to *un*set these options in a shell, if you set them to try them out.